# Scroll to another div in same page not working in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to scroll to different sections in my homepage. I have created an anchor tag with href to ids of various sections.
[image]
The URL on the site is changing when clicked on the navbar but the page isn't scrolling down to different sections.
[image]
I made sure to check the same ids are given to the divs of the components.
This is my navbar component

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { menuItems } from './menu'
import styles from './NavBar.module.css'
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Drawer from '../../assets/drawer.svg'
import { scrollContext } from "../../context/scroll/scroll"


const NavBar = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [showMenu, setshowMenu] = useState(false);
  const [allNavLinks, setallNavLinks] = useState([...menuItems]);
  const [activeIndex, setactiveIndex] = useState(1);
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
if (location == "/#") {
  allNavLinks[0].isactive = true;
  allNavLinks[4].isactive = false;
}
else if (location == "/team") {
  allNavLinks[4].isactive = true;
  allNavLinks[0].isactive = false;
}
  }, [])


  const changeShowMenu = () => {
  setshowMenu((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const changeactiveLink = (id) => {
  setactiveIndex(id);
  if (showMenu) {
    setshowMenu(false);
   }
  };

  const clickOutsidedrawer = () => { };
  const [showModal, setshowModal] = useState(false)
  const onLogin = () => {
    alert("Trying to login")
  }

  return (
<div className={`${styles.container} text-white text-lg font-bold flex sm:justify-between items-center p-5 px-[7vw] h-[15vh] `}>

    <div className="navLeft navLogo flex items-center  justify-center relative w-full sm:w-1/3 sm:justify-start sm:gap-2 text-3xl uppercase">
        <img src={Drawer} alt="navigation drawer" className="w-[10%] absolute left-0 sm:hidden" />
        <img src="/logo.svg" className=' w-[75px] self-center sm:w-[75px]' alt="" />
        <span className='hidden sm:block text-5xl'>LIFES</span>
    </div>
    <div className="navRight hidden sm:flex gap-5 items-center w-[35%] justify-between">
       <ul className="flex items-center justify-around w-[70%]">
      {allNavLinks.map(navLink => {
          
            return(
              <a href={navLink.link} key={navLink.id} className="hover:cursor-pointer" id={navLink.ref} >
             
              <li  >
                  {navLink.label}
                </li>
             
              </a>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
        <button className="loginButton rounded-2xl border bg-white text-black flex items-center py-2 px-5 " onClick={(e) =>navigate('/login')} >
          Login
        </button>
        {/* ADD A lOGIN MODAL */}


    </div>
  {/* nav drawer */}
  {/* navigation drawer */}
  <div
    className={
      showMenu
        ? `${styles.drawer}  absolute left-0 flex flex-col gap-1 justify-center items-center lg:hidden`
        : `hidden`
    }
  >
    <div
      className={`${showMenu ? "block" : "hidden"
        } left-[15px] top-[25px]`}
      onClick={changeShowMenu}
    >
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        strokeWidth={1.5}
        stroke="currentColor"
        className="w-8 h-8"
      >
        <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <ul className="flex flex-col items-center mt-10 gap-5">
      {allNavLinks.map((nav) => {
        return (
          <li
            key={nav.id}
            className={`text-md ${activeIndex === nav.id && styles.activeLink
              } py-1`}
          >
            <a
              href={nav.path}
              className={``}
              onClick={() => changeactiveLink(nav.id)}
            >
              {nav.title}
            </a>
          </li>
        );
      })}

      
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

How can I make it work?